# How to use Jquery price slider in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2-enterprise, price-slider

I want to display price slider in category page side menu using Jquery price slider. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/prashant1990-priceslider.html

Comment: You can find free layered navigation modules. It will help you.

Comment: I don't want to use third party extension. How to achieve this without using extension?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below module, I already use this module its working fine for me.

first try with this extension :

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-ajax-layered-navigation

than user another one :

https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-price-slider

**hope its work for you**

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.3 enterprise edition and I have already tried this extension but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Can you please suggest whether it's possible to implement this feature without using any extension?

Comment: have you try mageplaza price slider- https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-ajax-layered-navigation

Comment: Is the extension you're referring here works with EE?

Comment: not conform but try i hope its working for you.

Comment: Ok. Let me try it. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I have tried the extension as you suggest but in the layered navigation, I'm getting the normal price range filter instead of slider. Please comment